# Does the page timeout interrupt loop execution inside page context ? Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, timeout, puppeteer

Considering the following example :

```
page.setDefaultTimeout(2000); // set a default timeout of 2s on the page

await page.$eval('selector', (el) => {
    while (true) {
        // do some stuff
    }
});
```

What will happen ? Does the loop blocks the execution forever or is it interrupted by the timeout ?

Comment: It's easy to try it and see. You're missing `await`s so as-is, the code is broken.

Comment: `page.setDefaultTimeout()` returns `void` so no `await` needed on it

Comment: `page.$eval` needs `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following test the answer is **NO** the `page timeout` **will not interrupt an endless loop** in `pageFunction`.

```js
 page.setDefaultTimeout(1000);
 await page.exposeFunction('log', (val) => console.log(val));
 await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
 await page.$eval('body', (el) => {
     let a=0;
     while (true) {
        log(a++);
     }
 });
```